# IntelliJ CE Red Markers

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, coding-style, warnings, scalastyle

My IntelliJ is showing warnings in Red color. For example "Whitespace at end of line", "Are you sure you want to println? If yes, ...."

I have tried changing the setting at many place, no avail.
For now, I am using Scala.

[image]

EDIT: I still want to see the warning, but not in Red color. I have tried changing this in the following settings, but it did not help. Where else can this be fixed?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share the complete file to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you clone some template? Looks like scalastyle error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MateuszKubuszok mentioned in the comment, it is a [scalastyle](https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle) error. [Here](https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle/blob/ec14399543d2d5ccf93c3713aa5df21793844791/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L43) is the place that holds part of the message you are seeing. Basically you have three options:

1. Fix that warning by removing the spaces. (The best IMHO)
2. Wrap this line in `scalastyle:off` as suggested:

   ```scala
   // scalastyle:off
   println("Why?") // Followed by spaces          
   // scalastyle:on
   ```
3. Disable this rule. At the root of this project there is a file called `scalastyle-config.xml`. In it there is a line:

   ```
   <check level="warning" class="org.scalastyle.file.WhitespaceEndOfLineChecker" enabled="true"></check>
   ```

   Change it into:

   ```
   <check level="warning" class="org.scalastyle.file.WhitespaceEndOfLineChecker" enabled="false"></check>
   ```

   will make this rule to not check your code.

Comment: Hi Tomer, my bad. My question is I still want to see the warning, but not in Red color.

Comment: @kk1957 What is your `level`? in `scalastyle-config.xml` in the line I specified in section 3?

Comment: works! The level was defined to be error.